# How to Initialize An Array of the Information and Append

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am looking to be able to initialize an empty array structure that has the ability to `.append()` and can hold information similar to:

```
var locations = [
    ["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
    ["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
    ["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
]
```

Is this data type of an array of an array of dictionaries? I am looking to be able to access `title` , `latitude`, and `longitude` by `location` and I have never worked with something like this, so I am not sure how to initialize and `.append()`

Comment: That's an array of dictionaries. But really if you're looking to store an array of static fields, you want an array of structs instead.

Comment: *Tip:*  Option-click on `locations` in the Xcode source editor and you'll see the type. (But then follow Hamish's suggestion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is an array of dictionaries: `[[String : Any]]`.

As @Hamish suggested in the comments, you'd be better served to store your data as an array of structs.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
struct Location: CustomStringConvertible {
    var title: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    var description: String { return "(title: \(title), latitude: \(latitude), longitude: \(longitude))"}
}

var locations = [
    Location(title: "New York, NY", latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228),
    Location(title: "Los Angeles, CA", latitude: 34.052238, longitude: -118.243344),
    Location(title: "Chicago, IL", latitude: 41.883229, longitude: -87.632398)
]

// Append a new location...    
locations.append(Location(title: "Boston, MA", latitude: 42.3601, longitude: -71.0589))

print(locations)
```

> ```
> [(title: New York, NY, latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228),
> (title: Los Angeles, CA, latitude: 34.052238, longitude: -118.243344),
> (title: Chicago, IL, latitude: 41.883229, longitude: -87.632398),
> (title: Boston, MA, latitude: 42.3601, longitude: -71.0589)]
> ```

```
func lookUp(title: String, in locations: [Location]) -> [Location] {
    return locations.filter { $0.title.range(of: title) != nil }
}

print(lookUp(title: "CA", in: locations))
```

> ```
> [(title: Los Angeles, CA, latitude: 34.052238, longitude: -118.243344)]
> ```

```
print(lookUp(title: "Chicago", in: locations))
```

> ```
> [(title: Chicago, IL, latitude: 41.883229, longitude: -87.632398)]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an array of dictionaries, but the dictionary values are either type `String` or `Double`, so to accommodate both of these values, the dictionary type will be `<String: Any>`.

If you were explicitly decalairing the type for the locations variable (instead of being inferred) it would be:

```
var locations: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = ...
```

To access the values in the array you can use index subscripting where you pass in an `Int` for the index of the dictionary at that position:

```
let firstLocation = locations[0]
// firstLocation: [String: Any]
// firstLocation -> [ "title": "New York, NY", "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228]
```

You can dig in deeper with a second subscript accessing the value for the dictionary key:

```
let firstLocationTitle = locations[0]["title"]
// firstLocationTitle: Any?
// firstLocationTitle -> New York, NY

let message = "I'm in" + firstLocationTitle
// fails because operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Any?'
```

To get access to the underlying String type, you need to cast from `Any?` to `String`:

```
let firstLocationTitle = locations[0]["title"] as! String
// firstLocationTitle: String
// firstLocationTitle -> New York, NY

let message = "I'm in" + firstLocationTitle
// message -> "I'm in New York, NY"
```

To append a new location, it just needs to be the same type, here's how you could add a Boston dictionary to locations:

```
let boston: [String: Any] = ["title": "Boston, MA", "latitude": 39.713054, "longitude": -88.632398]
locations.append(boston)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Dictionary` version of the answer from @vacawama. It is an alternative that might suit certain use cases better (or worse).

There are a few notable improvements in this version:

1. Looking up a key in a dictionary is very fast O(1), where as using `find()` on an array performs quite poorly as the list grows into the hundreds of cities O(N).
2. Strings are allocated on the heap. This means the coordinate `struct` as designed will behave similar to a `class` in terms of performance (slower). Your question did not present a strong case for storing the location name in the `struct`.

First create a struct to represent a coordinate.

```
struct Coordinate {
    /// Latitude in decimal notation
    let latitude: Double

    /// Longitude in decimal notation
    let longitude: Double
}
```

Then create the empty collection (per your question)

```
/// Empty mapping of location string to latitude-longitude
var coordinates = [String: Coordinate]()
```

Here’s an example of one way to populate the dictionary

```
/// Populate the locations
coordinates["New York, NY"] = Coordinate(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
coordinates["Los Angeles, CA"] = Coordinate(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
coordinates["Chicago, IL"] = Coordinate(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
```

Example output:

```
print(coordinates["New York, NY"] ?? "Unknown Location”)
> "Coordinates(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007227999999998)”
```

That’s it!

---

### A little further...

#### If the locations are known in advance, and if there are not hundreds of them, you might try using a string-backed `enum`

The above should answer the original question, however Swift allows even more interesting approaches using the type system.

We have guaranteed that a `Coordinate` is a pair of `Double` numbers, great! But, there are no guarantees about the integrity of a location. Later on you might accidentally type `coordinates[“New york, NY”]`. This will fail because “york” is lowercase! (and also in ever other answer currently posted). Here’s the enum:

```
enum Location: String {
    case NY_NewYork = "New York, NY"
    case CA_LosAngeles = "Los Angeles, CA"
    case IL_Chicago = "Chicago, IL"
}
```

And change our dictionary key and usage accordingly

```
/// Empty mapping of location string to latitude-longitude
var coordinates = [Location: Coordinate]()

/// Populate the locations
coordinates[.NY_NewYork] = Coordinate(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
coordinates[.CA_LosAngeles] = Coordinate(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
coordinates[.IL_Chicago] = Coordinate(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
```

We still have the original “New York, NY” title, but it is represented statically as the value `Location.NY_NewYork`. This means that the compiler will catch any mistakes that you might make!

One more thing: now that the location is a static constant value, we can actually put it back inside the `struct` without incurring a dreaded heap allocation! (The struct value will be a reference to the enumerated value).

Here’s the final version:

```
enum Location: String {
    case NY_NewYork = "New York, NY"
    case CA_LosAngeles = "Los Angeles, CA"
    case IL_Chicago = "Chicago, IL"
}

struct Coordinate {
    /// The logical name of the location referenced by this coordinate
    let location: Location

    /// Latitude in decimal notation
    let latitude: Double

    /// Longitude in decimal notation
    let longitude: Double
}

/// Empty mapping of location string to latitude-longitude
var coordinates = [Location: Coordinate]()

/// Populate the locations
coordinates[.NY_NewYork] = Coordinate(location: .NY_NewYork, latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
coordinates[.CA_LosAngeles] = Coordinate(location: .CA_LosAngeles, latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
coordinates[.IL_Chicago] = Coordinate(location: .IL_Chicago, latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
// or if initializing from a data source, something like...
// if let loc = Location(rawValue: "Chicago, IL") {
//     coordinates[loc] = Coordinate(location: loc, latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228)
// }
```

And the output

```
print(coordinates[Location.NY_NewYork] ?? "uknown”)
> "Coordinate(location: Location.NY_NewYork, latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007227999999998)”
```

Cool! Now we have perfect type-safety, the convenience of keeping the location title in there, and a very high-performance architecture.

This is what makes Swift a special tool for iOS.

Comment: A dictionary lookup is faster, but requires that you have the exact key you are looking for.  If performance is an issue, you could easily build a lookup dictionary from the array of structs that maps city name to index into the array.  You can also use the array of structs to answer questions like "give me all cities north of Chicago" or give me all cities in "CA".

Comment: @vacawama Yep, I have actually revised my answer to expand on that “exact key” concept. The OP didn’t say he didn’t know the keys – actually it seems like he probably does. Regardless, if you want to make that case, you’re going to need a fuzzier matcher than you provided. Also, if you’re looking for distances or direction, you’re going to need a more specialized collection and logic overall.

Comment: You can't add enum values at runtime.  OP wanted to be able to append additional items to the database, and the enum wouldn't allow you to do that.

Comment: I meant that you can only add cities to your `coordinates` dictionary that are already in your enum.  Image what would happen if you let the end user add a totally new location to locations like their home or favorite vacation spot.

Comment: Yeah, that’s true. There is already a disclaimer "If the locations are known in advance, and if there are not hundreds of them"

Comment: Oh OK.  I missed that.  All designs have tradeoffs and there is no one-size-fits-all design.  It's good to know up front what the tradeoffs are.

Comment: @vacawama Totally! There are many correct answers and the question was quite vague.

Answer (score 0):

```
var locations = [
    ["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
    ["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
    ["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
]
for(loc) in locations {
    if let title = loc["title"] as? String, let lat = loc["latitude"] as? Double, let lon = loc["longitude"] as? Double {
        print("title: \(title), latitude:\(lat), longitude:\(lon)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to use **just** a Dictionary with a tuple. That way you can insure you have unique keys.

```
var myCoordinates:(Float,Float)?
var myCities = [String:(Float,Float)]()
```

The key (String type) is the city name and the tuple (the two float types) are your longitude/latitiude values.

```
myCities["New York, NY"] = (40.713054,-74.007228)
myCoordinates = myCities["New York, NY"]?
print(String(describing: myCoordinates?.0))
print(String(describing: myCoordinates?.1))
myCoordinates = myCities["Los Angeles, CA"]
print(String(describing: myCoordinates?.0))
print(String(describing: myCoordinates?.1))
```

This code yields the following console output:

```
Optional(40.7130547)
Optional(-74.007225)
nil
nil
```